# WebWorkerの実行速度を制御したい

Tags: javascript, web-worker

JavaScriptでWebWorkerを使用しています。
私が作ったシステムではWebWorkerの値を送受信する速度が速すぎて、
HTMLに反映される処理が追い付いていない問題が発生しています。
そこで、sleep関数を定義することで、制御することを考えました。

```
/*Sleep関数 */
function Sleep( milii_second ){
    let start   = new Date().getTime();
    let end     = new Date().getTime();
    while( end < start + milii_second ){
        end = new Date().getTime()
    };
    return;
}
Sleep(40);
```

こちらの関数はビジーウェイトと呼ばれるもので、CPUに負荷がかかるのであまり使用したくありません。しかし、WebWorker内で使用しているためか、ブラウザが止まりませんでした。止まっていることに気づいていないだけ？

```
/*sleep関数(setInterval)
function sleep(waitSec, callbackFunc){
    let spanedSec = 0;
    let id = setInterval(function () {
        spanedSec++;
        if(spanedSec >= waitSec) {
            clearInterval(id);
            if (callbackFunc) callbackFunc();
        }
    }, 40);
}

sleep(5, function () {});
```

こちらのsleep関数を利用するとCPUに負荷はかからないので、使用したいのですが、WebWorker内で使用しても、sleep関数を入れても効果がありませんでした。使い方が間違っているかもしれません。
私の推測で申し訳ありませんが、WebWorkerはそもそもマルチスレッドで処理されています。
setIntervalやsetTimeoutは非同期処理であるため、利用しても、効果がないではないかと考えています。

一応、ビジーウェイトのsleep関数だと実行速度を制御させることができました。
ほかに便利な関数あるいは改善箇所があれば、ぜひ教えていただいてもよろしいでしょうか

よろしくお願いいたします。

HTMLの描画を行うスレッド(メインスレッド)と
メインスレッドで受け渡した値に応じた
関数を実行する(実行スレッド)の２つに分けています

Comment: JavaScriptはイベントドリブンであるため特定スレッドの処理を意図的に遅延させるような関数は用意されていません。質問文にある`setInterval`を使ったsleep関数は精度の良くない`setTimeout`の実装のように見えますが、スレッドの動作を停止させるものではありません。WebWorkerで処理したい内容と、WebWorkerからメインスレッド（HTML描画を行うスレッド）への通知を分離して、`setInterval`や`setTimeout`などで通知頻度を調整するのが１つの手段かと思います。これ以上はもう少し具体的なコードや目的等がわからないと回答が難しいかと思います。

Comment: setInterval版sleep()で遅延効果がないのは使い方が間違っているのだと思われます。Worker内でsetInterval()やsetTime()を使ってそのスレッドがスリープするかどうかはブラウザの実装依存かもしれませんね。質問者さんがsetInterval版sleep()でビジーにならないと確認できたのならそれで良いですが。